# Windows Anytime upgrade not available in this edition of Windows 7 (Starter) even though I live in the U.S

Tags: windows-7, anytime-upgrade

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Starter and a key for Windows 7 Home Premium. I'd like to upgrade the system to the Home Premium. When I try to use the Windows Anytime Upgrade, it informs me that "Windows Anytime Upgrade not available in this edition of Windows".

I'm confused because I thought this limitation shouldn't exist for laptops in the U.S. Is there a setting somewhere that is causing this error?

Comment: @Ramhound: That is not true, see the notes here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/help/videos/upgrade-to-another-edition-of-windows-7-by-using-windows-anytime-upgrade

Comment: @mugetsu: What region does your public IP address display as? e.g. try http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: @James shows im in the u.s

Answer (score -1):

It may be trying to upgrade you to Win 8 64 bit, you would need 32 bit Win 8. You won't be able to upgrade to 7 as it isn't available to buy from Microsoft any more, only Win 8.1 is.

If you have already bought it, try a clean install.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx#editions

This should help you out with any luck. Happy upgrading!

Comment: What does Windows 8 have to with this question

Comment: The fact Microsoft will try and sell you it over 7 because they no longer sell 7. I thought I made that pretty clear. Like I then said, 'if you've already bought it, try a clean install'. What's to downvote about that.

Comment: The downvote is because you claim it "might be trying to upgrade you to Windows 8" even though the user clearly is NOT attempting to do that, and that wouldn't happen, through the `Windows Anytime` feature.  Its still possible to upgrade Starter to Home Premium you just can't purchase the license directly from Microsoft through the `Windows Anytime` feature

Comment: "even though the user clearly is NOT attempting to do that"

I said Windows might be trying to do that as Win 7 is not offered any more for general sale.

You sir have a superiority complex. Don't use caps it makes you look like a douche. I'm trying to help here. You are downvoting me for helping. Guess I'll not bother in future. Enjoy 'contributing' here by downvoting newcomers to minus values. I'll go help somewhere that thanks me for it instead. You can reign supreme in your little imaginary world whilst I go get a life.

Comment: You asked the reason I issued a downvote. I explain the reason. Your answer is not well researched. I didn't use "caps" unless you count the single word, and if that makes me a douche, then I will accept that title. **The question had nothing to do with Windows 8.1, yet your answer, talks about it**. If you improve your answer, I have no problem, removing the downvote. You can't have negative reputation, and your lack of reputation, is because of the low qualit of your answers.  Lets not forget.  In the future I won't explain the downvote if this is the type of reaction I should expect.